# How to increament value of variable after click button and send it from one to another php function?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

My english isn't very good but i will try explain my problem. I have a form in php with dynamically added rows (after clicking button the row is added). If form is fill properly, after submitting, the pdf is generated. In other case the form must be corrected and the values of earlier filled fields should be remebered. It's work for simple field but for dynamically added rows it's not work. 
I set variable $_POST['whichRow'] to send it after each loop iteration, from function generateAddedRows() to function addRows2(). Unfortunetly it doesn' work, the variable $_POST['whichRow'] in function addRows2() return NULL.

This function is running if the form was filled wrong. It's create the earlier dynamically added rows:

```
$_POST['whichRow'] = 1;

function generateAddedRows(){
    $_POST['whichRow']++;

    while($personsArrayLength>1){

        echo '
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    var i = 2;
                    var rowTemplate2 = jQuery.format($("#template2").html());
                    addRow2();

                    function addRow2(){
                        var ii = i++;
                        $("#app_here2").append(rowTemplate2(ii));
                        $("#delete_" + ii).click(function(){
                            $("#row_" + ii).remove();
                        });
                    }
                });

            </script>
        ';
        $personsArrayLength--;
        $myValue++;
    }
}
```

This function create a dynamcally added rows. I try to get the $_POST['value'] as value of each row:

```
function addRows2(){
    global $personsError_css;
    $personsArray = $_POST['persons'];

        $html = '<table id="template2" align="right" style="display:none; ">
            <tr id="row_{0}">
                <td><input type="text" name="persons[]" value="'.$personsArray[$_POST['whichRow']].'"></td>
                <td><img src="/../_img/row_del.png" id="delete_{0}" alt="usun"></td>
            </tr>

           </table>
            .
            .
            .
        </table>';
        return $html;
}
```

I insert here some screens to better understand this problem.

This is form before validating. Each field is filled:
[image]

This is form after validating. The form was filled wrongly so it should be corrected. The earlier entering values should be remembered but as you can see it's not:

[image]

I hope so you understand my problem. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I see some different possible problems here:

- Are you sure that `$_POST['persons']` contains everything properly?
- If you are going to call a function, you have to define it first:

  ```
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         /* CODE */
         function addRow2(){
             /* CODE */
         });

         addRow2();    
      });
  </script>
  ```
- Your code is a little messy. Be careful with those function names. You are using the same name for javascript and PHP functions.
- I think it's not a good idea to use a `$_POST` variable to store data on demand. The POST request is who creates the POST variables, I don't even know what happens if you modify them in execution time. That scenario is perfect for a global variable.